# extern storage class and global variables

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are extern variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

What is the difference between extern storage class and global variables in C programming language.? To me it seems like they both are same thing .Please clarify.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `extern` variable is a **declaration** of a variable which is **defined** in *another unit*.

You **declare** it in `.h` file:

```
extern int global_var;
```

and if you want to use it in `.c` file you **define** it in the *global scope*. And you should `include` the `.h` file in the source file that uses it.

**Global variables** are ariables which were **declared** outside of a block.
They can be accessed *everywhere* in the program.

Please note that it is very important to know the difference between **Declaring** a variable and **Defining** it:

- **Declare a variable** - There is something with this name, and it has this type. The compiler can use this variable without the need of all the definition of it.
- **Define a variable**  - Provide all of the information to create this variable.